# Parse and extract required text from text files using C#

Tags: c#, sql, html, regex

I have some text files with some useful data wrapped in between HTML tags like `<td>`, `<span>`, etc. I want to write a program which extracts the data in between the tags.

The text file contains other junk data too. I would also like to store these extracted data into SQL Table. Anyone who can guide me in right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Don't mention Regex and HTML in the same question on this site -- it's a sin!! ;-)

You likely want the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).